# Unable to execute stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute a ^stored procedure within a main stored procedure. But it's not working.

> Error(11,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FN_UPD" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "FN_UPD" to continue.

The code:

```
create or replace
procedure FN_READ

is
   cursor C_1 is select distinct(COLUMN1) from TB_SOURCE;
   cursor C_2 is select distinct(COLUMN2) from TB_SOURCE;
   cursor C_3 is select distinct(COLUMN3) from TB_SOURCE;
BEGIN

    for f in C_1
    LOOP
   EXEC FN_UPD('A', 'A');

    end LOOP;


    for f in C_2
    LOOP
   EXEC PROCEDURE FN_UPD(f.COLUMN2, 'M')
    end LOOP;

    for f in C_3
    LOOP
    EXEC FN_UPD(f.COLUMN3, 'O')

    end LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR-    '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: i suggest reading about [FORALL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm)

Answer (score 2):

`EXEC` (and the same applies to `EXEC PROCEDURE`) does not work in PL/SQL, use the procedure name directly:

```
BEGIN
    FN_UPD('A', 'A');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 EXEC FN_UPD(f.COLUMN3, 'O')
```

and

```
 EXEC PROCEDURE FN_UPD(f.COLUMN2, 'M')
```

with

```
FN_UPD(f.COLUMN3, 'O');
```

and

```
FN_UPD(f.COLUMN2, 'M');
```

respectively.

Note the trailing `;`.

So, your procedure becomes

```
create or replace
procedure FN_READ

is
   cursor C_1 is select distinct(COLUMN1) from TB_SOURCE;
   cursor C_2 is select distinct(COLUMN2) from TB_SOURCE;
   cursor C_3 is select distinct(COLUMN3) from TB_SOURCE;
BEGIN

    for f in C_1 LOOP
        FN_UPD('A', 'A');
    end LOOP;


    for f in C_2 LOOP
        FN_UPD(f.COLUMN2, 'M')
    end LOOP;

    for f in C_3 LOOP
         FN_UPD(f.COLUMN3, 'O')
    end LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR-    '||SQLERRM);
END;
```